# how can i generate a network diagram from external data in VISIO

Tags: microsoft-visio

i have 2 database tables:

1. Components (this has fields id, name and componentType)
2. Dependencies (this has fields id, componentId, dependencyComponentId)

A component type can be a client, server or database

I would like to generate a visio diagram that shows the dependency tree between this data and show appropriate images for components (client image, server image, etc)

Is this possible.  I read all of the link shapes to records but:

1. This doesn't seem to support multiple tables.
2. I want to autogenerate the whole visio diagram (instead of linking shapes after the fact)

Comment: Shouldn't this be on StackOverflow?

Comment: @TheLQ Not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s relatively simple to generate network diagrams in Visio. First create the detailed network diagram with Visio network shapes and then import the external data about equipment in your drawing by following these steps:

1. On the Data menu, click Link Data to Shapes.
2. On the first page of the Data Selector Wizard, choose which of the following types of data sources you want to use:
   • Microsoft Excel Workbook
   • Microsoft Access database
   • Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services List
   • Microsoft SQL Server database
   • Other OLEDB or ODBC Data Source
   • Previously created connection
3. Complete the remainder of the wizard.
   Note:  If you choose an option other than an Excel workbook, Access database, or SharePoint list on the first page of the wizard, you may be temporarily diverted to the Data Connection Wizard in the course of completing the Data Selector Wizard.

Comment: I dont see how this is an answer. At no point in the wizard can you select to use the data to create relation. If i'm wrong, please clarify the answer.